# HTTP POST returns 400 when trying to save object in MongoDB

Tags: java, json, spring, mongodb, spring-webflux

I am new to reactive programming and I'm having the following problem.
I have an object of the `Human.java` class which has the properties: id, firstName, lastName and List<Hobbies>. An object can be saved in MongoDB and all objects can be listed. I've used *ReactiveMongoTemplate* methods to save and list said objects. For *MongoDB* I've created a container in *Docker*. However, when I try to send a *POST Request with Postman*, I always receive a *400 status code* and I cannot understand what is the problem.

Below are listed my classes:

**Human.java**

```
@Document
public class Human {

    @Id
    @JsonIgnore
    private String id;
    
     private String firstName;

     private String lastName;
     
     private List<Hobbies>hobbies;
     
     public Human(String fName, String lName, List<Hobbies> hobb) {
         this.firstName= dNum;
         this.lastName= saNum;
         this.hobbies= hobb;
     }
     public String getId() {
         return this.id;
     }
     public String getFirstName() {
         return this.firstName;
     }
     
     public String getLastName() {
         return this.lastName;
     }
     
     public List<Hobbies> getHobbies() {
         return this.hobbies;
     }
     
     public void setFirstName(String fName) {
         this.firstName = fName;
     }
     
     public void setLastName(String lName) {
         this.lastName= lName;
     }
     
     public void setHobbies(List<Hobbies> hobb) {
         this.hobbies= hobb;
     }
    
}
```

**Hobbies.java**

```
public class Hobbies {
    
    private String type;
    
    public Hobbies(String typ) {
        this.type = typ;
    }
    
    public String getType() {
        return this.type;
    }
    
    public void setType(String typ) {
        this.type = typ;
    }

}
```

**HumanConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class HumanConfig {

    @Autowired
    MongoClient mongoClient;
    
    @Bean
    public ReactiveMongoTemplate reactiveMongoTemplate() {
        return new ReactiveMongoTemplate(mongoClient, "human");
    }
    
}
```

**HumanRouter.java**

```
@Configuration
public class HumanRouter {
    
    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> humanRoute(HumanHandler humHandler) {
        return RouterFunctions
            .route(GET("/api/listHumans").and(accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)),
                    humHandler::getAllHumans)
            .andRoute(POST("/api/newHuman").and(accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)),
                    humHandler::create);
    }
}
```

**HumanHandler.java**

```
@Component
public class HumanHandler {
    
    private final HumanService humService;

    @Autowired
    public HumanHandler(HumanService humService) {
        this.humService= humService;
    }
    
    public Mono<ServerResponse> getAllHumans(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
LOGGER.info("Handling HTTP request for getting all humans");
        Flux<Human> result = humService.getAllHumans();
        return result
                   .collectList()
                   .flatMap(h -> {
                       if(h.isEmpty()) {
                             return ServerResponse.notFound().build();

                           }
                           else {
                             return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(fromValue(h));
                           }
                       }).log();
    }
        
        public Mono<ServerResponse> create(ServerRequest request ){
            public Mono<ServerResponse> create(ServerRequest request ){
        Mono<Human> humToCreate = request.bodyToMono(Human.class).log();
LOGGER.info("Handling HTTP request for craeting newHuman");
        Mono<Human> created = humService.createHum(humToCreate).log();
       LOGGER.debug("Human created");
        Mono<Object> id = created.map(item -> item.getId());
        return ServerResponse.created(UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath(request.uri()+ "/"+ id).build().toUri())
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(created.map(item -> item.getId()), String.class);
        
        }

}
```

**HumanService.java**

```
@Service
public class HumanService {

    @Autowired
    ReactiveMongoTemplate mongo;
    
    public Flux<Human> getAllHumans(){
        return mongo.findAll(Human.class);
    }

    public Mono<Human> createHum(Mono<Human> human){
        return mongo.save(human);
    }
```

**HumanApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"human"})
public class HumanApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HumanApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

The json object i put in Postman in the body for a POST Request looks like this:

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Johnson",
    "hobbies": [
        {
            "type": "reading"
        },
        {
            "type": "travelling"
        }
    ]
}
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: "3.8"

services:
    mongodb:
        image: mongo
        container_name: human
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
        volumes:
            - data:/data
        environment:
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=rootuser
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpass
    mongo-express:
        image: mongo-express
        container_name: mongo-express-human
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8081:8081
        environment:
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=rootuser
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=rootpass
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb

volumes:
    data: {}

networks:
    default:
        name: mongodb_network_v2
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.username=rootuser
spring.data.mongodb.password=rootpass
spring.data.mongodb.database=human
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
server.error.include-message=always
```

I can't seem to understand what is wrong with my code.

EDIT: After adding some changes to **HumanHandler.java** ,i am able to see the logs after sending a POST Request. It brings the following error:

```
2022-05-02 15:30:55.452 ERROR 15064 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.Mono.OnErrorResume.1             : onError(org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebInputException: 400 BAD_REQUEST "Failed to read HTTP message"; nested exception is org.springframework.core.codec.DecodingException: JSON decoding error: Cannot construct instance of `reactive.Hobbies` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `reactive.Hobbies` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (io.netty.buffer.ByteBufInputStream); line: 6, column: 13] (through reference chain: reactive.Human["hobbies"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]))
2022-05-02 15:30:55.457 ERROR 15064 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.Mono.OnErrorResume.1
```

**SOLUTION:** As suggested by Michael McFadyen, an additional **@NoArgsConstructor** annotation was added to **Human** and **Hobbies** **POJO**

Comment: Did you verify the username, password, host and port. You can do this with a desktop client like `Heidi` for windows or `DBeaver` for linux

Comment: @DavidKariuki I checked username, password, host, and port with MongoDB Compass and everything is fine.

Comment: Have you added the mongodb dependency

Comment: yes i have added it

Comment: Update: When a remove the List<Hobbies> property from the constructor of Human.java, with the code above the object it is saved with Status code 201. So, the problem only occurs when I try to save this additional list of hobbies.

Comment: are there any relevant logs from your application when this occurs?

Comment: @MichaelMcFadyen i edited and added the error from the logs into the question.

Comment: Jackson is failing to deserialise your json to a instance of `Hobbies`. Try adding no args constructors to both `Hobbies` and `Human` POJOs

Comment: @MichaelMcFadyen Thanks a lot! This solved my problem! Why did Jackson need an additional NoArgsConstructor annotation?

Comment: I'll provide a more fleshed out answer below and provide some additional links to useful resources

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0    
    https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    ...

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        ...

    </dependencies>
    ...

</project>
```

#### application.properties file

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://rootuser: 
rootpass@<cluster>.mongodb.net/mygrocerylist
spring.data.mongodb.database=calibration
```

Check this for more information -> [Spring Boot Integration with MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/compatibility/spring-boot)

Comment: i changed the application.properties file like you showed but still having the same problem

Comment: Please update the question with the errors you are getting

Comment: i edited and added the error from the logs into the question.